# Why I can not use "this" in AddOnItemTouchListener in another activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have `public class ContactsFragment : SupportFragment, IOnTouchListener`. 
Here is code inside of `ContactsFragment`:

```
{
    public Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView recView;
    ...
    recView.AddOnItemTouchListener(this);
}
```

So when I tried to put "`this`" inside of **`recView.AddOnItemTouchListener(this)`**, it always give me error

> it is not valid type in given context

Comment: What type does `AddOnItemTouchListener` expect as its parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
```

and

```
RecyclerView recView;
//...
//...
recView.AddOnItemTouchListener(new MyListener());
```

Now `MyListener` (which can be inside the same activity class) :

```
public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, RecyclerView.IOnItemTouchListener
{
    public MyListener()
    {
        //pass data if you want
    }
    public bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent @event)
    {
        //code here
    }
    public void OnRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(bool disallow)
    {
        //code here
    }
    public void OnTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent @event)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

You can remove `IOnTouchListener` from the top as:

```
public class ContactsFragment : SupportFragment
```

It should work.

**Edit:**

> it is not valid type in given context

Because you are doing :

```
public class ContactsFragment : SupportFragment, IOnTouchListener
```

instead of :

```
public class ContactsFragment : SupportFragment, RecyclerView.IOnItemTouchListener
```

and implement the methods:

```
public bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent @event)
{
    //code here
}
public void OnRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(bool disallow)
{
    //code here
}
public void OnTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent @event)
{
    ////code here
}
```

See [RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html) and [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: thank you! it woks , but anyway I don't understand why it doesn't recognize "this" in recView.AddOnItemTouchListener(this)

Comment: @Gold there is a difference between IOnTouchListener and RecyclerView.IOnItemTouchListener

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi By `IOnTouchListener`, I assume you mean `View.IOnTouchListener`, right?

Comment: @Gold The point is to look at the fully qualified name of the two interfaces named `IOnTouchListener`. You will find that either the packages or containing classes (or both) differ

Comment: Yes `View.IOnTouchListener`